# Using c# to Parse JSON data from Bureau of labor and statistics

Tags: c#, json, parsing, arraylist

I am using c# to parse JSON data from the Bureau of Labor and Statistics and am hitting a wall.  Ultimately I want to insert this data into a SQL table.  I can access certain parts of the JSON data but then I get errors when trying to access objects inside the array.  A link to the data is commented out in my code.  It can only be queried 25 times per day...

here is the JSON data from the BLS link (I'm using a txt file with this same data):

```
{
    "status": "REQUEST_SUCCEEDED",
    "responseTime": 66,
    "message": [],
    "Results": {
        "series": [
            {
                "seriesID": "CUUR0000SA0",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "237.838",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "237.945",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "238.316",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "238.654",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "238.638",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "237.805",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "236.599",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "236.119",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "234.722",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2015",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "233.707",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M13",
                        "periodName": "Annual",
                        "value": "236.736",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "234.812",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "236.151",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "237.433",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "238.031",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "237.852",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "238.250",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "238.343",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "237.900",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "237.072",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "236.293",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "234.781",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2014",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "233.916",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M13",
                        "periodName": "Annual",
                        "value": "232.957",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M12",
                        "periodName": "December",
                        "value": "233.049",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M11",
                        "periodName": "November",
                        "value": "233.069",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M10",
                        "periodName": "October",
                        "value": "233.546",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M09",
                        "periodName": "September",
                        "value": "234.149",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M08",
                        "periodName": "August",
                        "value": "233.877",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M07",
                        "periodName": "July",
                        "value": "233.596",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M06",
                        "periodName": "June",
                        "value": "233.504",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M05",
                        "periodName": "May",
                        "value": "232.945",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M04",
                        "periodName": "April",
                        "value": "232.531",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M03",
                        "periodName": "March",
                        "value": "232.773",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M02",
                        "periodName": "February",
                        "value": "232.166",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "year": "2013",
                        "period": "M01",
                        "periodName": "January",
                        "value": "230.280",
                        "footnotes": [
                            {}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm interested in trying to get the year, month, and value data from this, but I can only access the first parts using this c#.  I'm not sure how to get the rest of the JSON objects.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Net;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Web;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Globalization;
using System.ComponentModel;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;
using System.IO;


namespace ConsoleApplication5
{

class Person
{


    public string status { get; set; }

    public string responseTime { get; set; }


    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Status: {0}  \nResponse Time: {1}", status, responseTime);
    }


}

class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TryParse();
    }


    static void getJson()
    {

    }

    static void TryParse()
    {
        //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://api.bls.gov/publicAPI/v1/timeseries/data/CUUR0000SA0");
        //WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

        //string jsonString = response.ToString();

        string jsonString = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\h\Desktop\json.txt");

        JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        Person p1 = ser.Deserialize<Person>(jsonString);

        Console.WriteLine(p1);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

   }
}
```

Can someone help me access the year, periodName, and Value data?  If so I could probably shape it into an insert statement from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to Deserialize with this kind of class architecture

```
public class Rootobject
{
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int responseTime{ get; set; }
    public object[] message{ get; set; }
    public Results Results{ get; set; }
}
public class Results
{
    public Series[] series{ get; set; }
}
public class Series
{
    public string seriesID{ get; set; }
    public Datum[] data{ get; set; }
}
public class Datum
{
    public string year{ get; set; }
    public string period{ get; set; }
    public string periodName{ get; set; }
    public string value{ get; set; }
    public Footnote[] footnotes{ get; set; }
}
public class Footnote
{
}
```

and after this you can write

```
Deserialize<Rootobject>(jsonString);
```

Comment: Did this come from JSON to c#?  Because I was there and got this earlier when none of this was making sense but the way you put that code into context expanded my mind!  This is probably the most clear answer to this question I've seen on here.  Marking as answer asap.

Comment: Happy to help. :) no this is not from [JSON2C#](http://json2csharp.com/) I just went after your comment. :D

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Xamasoft JSON Class Generator,  You can use your browser to download a copy of the json data and then put it in that tool.  It will give you or at least help you build your class files needed to deserialize the data.  Also as another note,  I have found when working with these json classes if you use JSON.NET, you will use arrays[], but if your using RestSharp you will need to change them to List<>.